# Installing root library in VS13

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, root-framework

Hi i have probelm with root library.
I installed root library but it dosn't work at all.

I set Additional Include Directories to `%ROOTSYS%\lib` and
Additional Dependencies to `%ROOTSYS%\include%` but it doesn't work.
It returns "No such file or directory" if use any header from ROOT library.
for example won't compile.

```
#include "TCanvas.h"
int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

`%ROOTSYS%=E:\root\`
Edit
`Additional Dependencies = %ROOTSYS%\lib\*.lib`
`Additional Include Directories = %ROOTSYS%\include\`
Now includes but i see error

> Error 2   error C2065: 'TCanvas' : undeclared identifier

Comment: What's "root library"? Is the environment variable `%ROOTSYS%` set? If so, is it set to the correct value? And what does it mean when you say 'it doesn't compile "#include " or include "TCanvas"'?

Comment: %ROORSYS% is installation directory. I said that it doesn't include root library at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"#include <TCanvas>"
int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

This program is syntactically wrong. For some reason you have surrounded an entire `#include` statement with double quotes.

Have you tried:

```
#include "TCanvas.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

---

*Edit:* Well, you edited your post (twice as I was typing this!), changing everything and now you're essentially asking a different question... Let's see if we figure out what's going on.

You say that you set "`Additional Include Directories= %ROOTSYS%\lib*.lib`" but that's just wrong. "Additional Include Directories" is a set of directories where files to be included (using `#include`) can be found. But LIB files are not included using `#include` so that would be wrong. And of course, the syntax you cite: "`Additional Include Directories= %ROOTSYS%\lib*.lib`" is just flat out wrong. Also wrong is the "`Additional Dependencies = %ROOTSYS%\lib*.lib`" part.

You cannot fix this issue by randomly typing things in random places, as you seem to be, and hoping it will work. The world doesn't work that way.

You need to sit down and think about what you are trying to do, how your tools work, and how you can use them to do what you want/need to do.

Under your project settings go to **Linker** then under **General**, and set the **Additional Library Directories** entry. Please be sure to set it correctly: it must point to the directory where the library files that you want to link against are.

Comment: i am using second version

Comment: Are you sure? The "second version" includes a `.h` after `TCanvas`

Comment: Atm i am getting IntelliSense: identifier "TCanvas" is undefined
I am using this tutorial
http://www.pp.rhul.ac.uk/~connelly/tutorial/